# Can Subversion make an external in the same folder?

Tags: svn

I have a file in a directory that gets generated by a tool.  The name is not useful, so I'd like to add an external to that directory in order to give it a useful name.  That way I don't have to remember to rename the file every time the tool generates it again.  It doesn't seem like subversion can do this.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You could run the tool in batch script and rename the file there as well.

Comment: I'm not in control of everyone else who uses this tool.

Comment: SVN cannot solve the problem that you have. It must be handled differently. But now it seems that everyone else does not have a problem, ie. they don't mind renaming the file. So now the problem is not technical in nature anymore but managerial. Either convince them to change their ways, or join them in their ways.

Comment: That's a nonsense statement.  Most problems with technical solutions are not technical problems.  Technical solutions are usually better solutions.  This is a problem that should have a technical solution, and the technical solution is the best solution.  There's no reason why SVN can't do it.

Comment: There is a technical solution: use script to both run the tool and rename the file.

Comment: The tool is interactive.  Can't be scripted.